# How to use Computed Property in Nuxt js Layout Pages? (Composition Api)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I need to use computed property in my Category Layout page. When pages which are under this layout changed, computed must understand page changings. But I can't catch these changes and I can only catch changes if I use them in Watch property.

Layout.vue

```
v-app
  v-main 
    nuxt
    speed-dial-button(:page="page")
....

setup() {

    const route = useRoute();
    const page = ref('');
    const currentPath = computed(()=>route.value.path);


    if (['/eserler', '/en/artworks', '/ar/artworks'].includes(currentPath)) {
      page.value = i18n.t('general.addNewArtwork');
    } else if (['/kisiler', '/en/persons', '/ar/persons'].includes(currentPath)) {
      page.value = i18n.t('general.addNewPerson');
    } else if (['/etkinlikler', '/en/activities', '/ar/activities'].includes(currentPath)) {
      page.value = i18n.t('general.addNewActivity');
    }

console.log('page',page)
console.log('route',routePath)

  return { 
      page,
    };

  }
```

This will work if I load page first time or if I leave layout and return again .

Answer (score 2):

Your template will react, but not your log statement.  Put that in a watcher.  Set `deep` and `immediate` to your needs.

```
watch(route, value => {
  // your code here
  console.log(value.path)
}, {deep: true, immediate: true})
```

Comment: const currentPath = computed(()=>route.value.path) ;
    
    ` 
    if (['/eserler', '/en/artworks', '/ar/artworks'].includes(currentPath)) {
      page.value = i18n.t('general.addNewArtwork');
    } else if (['/kisiler', '/en/persons', '/ar/persons'].includes(currentPath)) {
      page.value = i18n.t('general.addNewPerson');
    } 
    return {page} 
    
    ` @Steven.

Comment: If i use if else condition , i cant see any changes also

Comment: Please do not post code snippets in comments @oktaytontaş

Comment: `deep` can have some big consequences regarding performance, keep that in mind.

Comment: i did question more clear @kissu

Comment: @kissu You can watch whatever you want using `watch( ()=>route.params, ...)` syntax for example, but I really doubt deep watching your route is going to be process intensive.